# Getting data in c# using odbc connection

Tags: c#

I tried to get data in crystal report using odbc from tally.erp9 with the following code.

```cs
    con.Open();
    OdbcCommand cmd=new OdbcCommand("Select Ledger.`$_Name`, Ledger.`$_ClosingBalance`, Ledger.`$_OpeningBalance` FROM AshtaMunicipalCouncil.TallyUser.Ledger Ledger", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataSet1 ds1 = new DataSet1();
    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds1.DataTable1);
    CrystalReport1 crv = new CrystalReport1();
    crv.SetDataSource(ds1);
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crv;
    crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    con.Close();
```

The above code gives me a result but it gives blank records and the crystal report doesn't display any pages.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/How-to-ask  ...

Comment: Remove the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 0):

```
    string queryString = "Select Ledger.`$_Name`, Ledger.`$_ClosingBalance`, Ledger.`$_OpeningBalance` FROM AshtaMunicipalCouncil.TallyUser.Ledger Ledger"";
    OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, con);
    DataSet1 ds1 = new DataSet1();
    // Open the connection and fill the DataSet.
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        adapter.Fill(ds1,"tbl");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

  // you can check your table count there
   MessageBox.Show (ds1.DataTable1.Rows.Count.ToString());

   CrystalReport1 crv = new CrystalReport1();
   crv.SetDataSource(ds1.DataTable1);
   crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crv;
   crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```